# Is there any difference between hooks posts_where with posts_join and posts_search performance wise?

Tags: query, performance, posts-where

I want to know which filter hook I should use that performs faster.

I did try both several times and I noticed that `posts_search` is a bit faster than using the combination of `posts_where` and `posts_join`

What is your take on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these hooks are called in a similar fashion and get passes similar data. Under normal circumstances there should be no meaningful performance difference between them.

One scenario I can think of is that if you aren't properly targeting your code to specific queries and it runs in *every* query then `posts_search` might fire less time, because other two are conditional on `suppress_filters` in query being disabled.

Comment: Yes indeed, I have seen the other two fire more times than `posts_search`. How can I avoid this? And what do you mean by "properly targeting your code to specific queries?"

Comment: @Gixty first thing you should do in your filter is checking if you want it to modify _this_ specific query being filtered. If this is done properly the performance impact shouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `if ($query->is_search())`